# How could I train on my own dataset with tensorflow/models/deeplab?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, image-segmentation

This is the [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab) to the repository on github.
I could run the example script to train and freeze the model. However, this can only be run on the dataset of pascal_voc or some other public dataset. I need to run it on my own dataset but I do not know what I should give to the `--tf_initial_checkpoint` option. When my dataset have different number of classes to the pascal_voc, I can not give an initial_checkpoint to it.